# Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll on UWP App Start

Tags: c#, dll, uwp

So when I start my UWP application I briefly get a splash screen and then an exception is thrown at:

> mscorlib.ni.dll!System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(string name, bool throwOnError, bool ignoreCase, bool reflectionOnly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool loadTypeFromPartialName)
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.RuntimeType.GetType(string typeName, bool throwOnError, bool ignoreCase, bool reflectionOnly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Type.GetType(string typeName, bool throwOnError)
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetWinRTResourceManager()
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoForUserPreferredLanguageInAppX()
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.get()
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.IO.FileLoadException.FormatFileLoadExceptionMessage(string fileName = "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", int hResult)
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.IO.FileNotFoundException.SetMessageField()
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.IO.FileNotFoundException.FileNotFoundException(string fileName, string fusionLog, int hResult)

There's no futher details other than "Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll".

Running a different UWP app such as the UWP blank template app works fine but this app specifically seems to have this problem.

I can reproduce the problem with a cut down version of my app that if needed can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/01euipylowpubux/ReproSample.7z?dl=0).

Comment: It should be an exception that occurs in your app. You must put breakpoints in order to find which part isn't working. Maybe an error in homepage constructor? Or in App.Xaml.Cs OnLaunched ?

Comment: The a breakpoint on the app's constructor aka App() is never hit. This is a post-constructor problem.

Comment: Is your app in an rep, so that you can compare the differences ?

Comment: It is but that didn't provide any insight as it needed fixes to compile when I retrieved it from the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that my App Package was corrupted or something so I deleted the package from [%localappdata%\packages]. You can find the your package name in the package manifest under the packaging section.

I figured this out by looking up the error I was getting in my event viewer which Microsoft's KB said that I should recreate my user account on the machine so that I'd get a new packages folder. But I found that simply deleting your project's package fixes it.

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac have you tried completely emptying your packages folder in localappdata?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I locate the folder with the name of my package and deleted. When I redeployed the app i get file not found exceptions again.

Comment: FileNotFound? That sounds like a different problem. This problem is in relation to a generic System.Exception.