# UWP App 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll Exception at startup

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution that contains a UWP project. Since my dev machine is Windows 8.1, I set up Remote Debug in another pc with Windows 10 installed in my same LAN. So, in Visual Studio I have to Right-Click to my UWP project and choose "Deploy" ensuring that "Remote Machine" is selected. After that I can Debug by hitting Remote Machine.

It worked, the app worked with no problem using this Remote Debug.

Since this UWP didn't have its own Assets (Logos, icons, etc) i opened the Manifest Designer to choose the images in Visual Assets section. Compiled, Deployed, and tried to remote debug again.
Now the app doesn't open, and I get the following Exceptions:

```
AppConsume.UWP.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\f736c883-f105-4d30-a719-4bf328872f5eVS.Debug_x86.JOHN_SMITH\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AppConsume.UWP.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\f736c883-f105-4d30-a719-4bf328872f5eVS.Debug_x86.JOHN_SMITH\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Excepción producida: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' en mscorlib.ni.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' en mscorlib.ni.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' en mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I tried other solutions like deleting Package Data folder described here: [Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll on UWP App Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960616/exception-thrown-system-exception-in-mscorlib-ni-dll-on-uwp-app-start), with no success.

Any Ideas?

UPDATE:
After checked System.IO.FileNotFoundException in Breakpoint settings I'm able to get more info about the current exception.

In `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);` from App.xaml.cs file is throwing this exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ClrCompression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

I also updated UWP package to 5.2.2

Comment: repair visual studio

Comment: Can you create a new project check if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile and run the application in Debug adjust build configuration.

In Visual Studio 2015, it in the Build > Configuration Manager window (this probably won't have happened by default). Tick the Build and Deploy boxes for the Universal project:

[image: Configuration Manager]

However, I still get some 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in log, but at least the app opens.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/